# Why can I modify const_cast-ed object in constexpr function?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, c++20, constexpr

I always assumed:

- writing to `const_cast` ed variable is UB
- there is no UB allowed in constexpr

So I am confused why this code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/s1fq9xaW8):

```
constexpr int fn(){
    int v = 42;
    return [v]() {
        const_cast<int&>(v)+=5;
        return v;
    }();
}
static constexpr auto val = fn();
int main() {
    return val;
}
```

note: I know there is no reason to not allow this to work since it is obvious what the result should be, I am more interested in the legal explanation why is this allowed.

Comment: example would be more clear if you give the two variables different names `return [x = v]() { ...`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That would break the example.

Comment: @Deduplicator not here: https://godbolt.org/z/zf3fM94vd. Not sure if I understand

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry. It would only remove one peculiarity of the example. Namely that the absence of `const` on the first `v` is important. I think I should catch some sleep...

Comment: It's not exactly unusual that something works because there is no reason (to use your words) "to not allow this to work".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is true:

> there is no UB allowed in constexpr

This part is not:

> writing to `const_cast`-ed variable is UB

The actual rule is, from [[dcl.type.cv]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4):

> Any attempt to modify ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr]) a const object ([basic.type.qualifier]) during its lifetime ([basic.life]) results in undefined behavior.

Note that the relevant part is whether the *object* is `const` or not - not whether any of the path that you took to get to it is `const`. And in this case, `v` is not a `const` object and nor is the one created in the lambda when you're copying it.

However, if you declare `v` to be `const`, then the one declared in the lambda would also be declared `const`, and thus the attempt to modify it would be undefined behavior. As a result, your code will no longer compile.

Comment: The lambdas member following so closely the original can be quite surprising. I wonder why they decided on that approach...

Comment: Since `v` is captured by value, isn't it const qualified because the closures `operator ()` is const qualified?  Or is it not even using the capture but using the variable from the outer scope?

Comment: @NathanOliver but the object on which `operator()` is called is not `const`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Thanks for completing the puzzle.  I was missing that bit of the object.  it's still declared as an `int`.

Comment: Ah, my mental model was wrong, I assumed mutable/(implicit) const) refer to member variables, but it is actually about operator(). :)

Answer (score 4):

The lambda expression translates to something similar to this:

```
struct unnamed {
    int v;
    int operator()() const {
       const_cast<int&>(v)+=5;
       return v;
    }
};
```

Without the `const_cast` you cannot modify `v` inside the `operator()` because the operator is a `const` method, but `v` itself is not `const`.

Same situation as with

```
struct foo {
    int x = 0;
    void operator() const {
        const_cast<int&>(x) += 42;
    }
};
```

Then this is "ok":

```
foo f;
f();
```

While this is undefined:

```
const foo f;
f();
```